# Non autonomous system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let us consider the wave equation $u_{tt}-u_{xx}=0$.

I have the two following questions:

a) If we have the boundary condition $u(0,t) = u(\pi+t,t) = 0$, for all $0 < t < \infty $ the given equation is non autonomous ?

b) If we consider $x$ as a function of $t$ i.e: $x =s(t)$, the given equation is non autonomous ?

Answer (score 0):

a) No, the form of the boundary conditions does not have any influence on the form of the PDE. Whatever the boundary conditions, the PDE itself is still autonomous.

b) Yes, in this case you obtain an equation for $F(t) = u(s(t),t)$ which depends explicitly on $s(t)$ and its derivatives.